# How to create iOS Screenshots for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Currently the simulator is not running in version 8 and so I'am not able to run the app on iPhone 6 and take screenshots for the app store.

Any ideas to create these files ?

Answer (score 0):

2 Options... Easiest way is to make copies of the iPhone 5 screenshots and enlarge/edit them. Or you can deploy to an actual device and take a screenshot from there.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to upload one set of screenshots for all iPhone families.

You can drag and drop your screenshots to each device family separately or click “Use 5.5-inch Display” to the media manager at iTunes Connect.

I am using [ShotBot](https://shotbot.io) for screenshots editing

Comment: Dang.. ShotBot is no longer accepting new accounts